# WebClient set value of input non text type

Tags: java, webclient

I am trying to get information from a webpage that needs login verification. I am using WebClient to accomplish this program, but I am running into trouble with getting and setting the value for an element.

I call this method to find the element:

```
HtmlInput username = currentPage.getElementByName("email");
```

The id of the element in the webpage is "email" but the type is of type="email", which seems to be causing this error in my code.

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.InputElementFactory createElementNS
INFO: Bad input type: "email", creating a text input
```

Is there anyway for it to recognize an element of type "email" instead of type "text"?